# How use google assistant as a text to speech tool Raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I have installed Google Assistant on Raspberry Pi 3. My program has some output as fixed audio. Can I use Raspberry Pi 3 to speech it? The problem is that when using other programs to read, I have to turn off google assistant and turn on when finished speechding. Because they all use the same output device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send text queries to the Assistant, and you could theoretically send a query in the background of "Repeat after me X" and the Assistant will repeat it. That may work for static or simple text.

Comment: I have used this for a while and it works well. But now, when I call "Reapeat after me X", I hear the answer "you said X". Is there a way to leave "you said"?

Comment: There's no easy way to remove that. You could try to splice the audio data coming back to only play after a certain time.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have found a way to solve the problem